# How to install magnolia's Travel Demo project on blank magnolia instance

Tags: magnolia

I'm trying to follow Travel Demo - for developers @ https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Travel+Demo+-+for+developers

- as suggested I've cloned project
- build it with skipped checkstyle option (already feel weird if I can't build project without undocumented tricks)
- Build succeed, but I have no clue what to do with it:

  - There no war files, only jars.
  - I know about training-developer-project bundle which I was able to build and run on local Tomcat

What I would like to do is:

- install Travel Demo project in blank magnolia web app maven project which I generated with maven archetype

Clarification: My idea was not just to install travel-demo as dependency but make it a part of my study project.

Update @Ducaz035: Running mvn -e -X clean install gives errors in checkstyle plugin:

```
[INFO] Starting audit...
C:\Magnolia_dev\demo-projects\community\magnolia-travel-demo\src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\model\NavigationAreaModelTest
.java:48: Missing a Javadoc comment.
C:\Magnolia_dev\demo-projects\community\magnolia-travel-demo\src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\setup\SetupDemoRolesAndGroups
TaskTest.java:54: Missing a Javadoc comment.
C:\Magnolia_dev\demo-projects\community\magnolia-travel-demo\src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\setup\TravelDemoModuleVersion
HandlerTest.java:75: Missing a Javadoc comment.
Audit done.
[INFO] There are 3 errors reported by Checkstyle 6.1.1 with magnolia-build-resources/checkstyle.xml ruleset.
[ERROR] src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\model\NavigationAreaModelTest.java[48] (javadoc) JavadocType: Missing a Javadoc co
mment.
[ERROR] src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\setup\SetupDemoRolesAndGroupsTaskTest.java[54] (javadoc) JavadocType: Missing a Ja
vadoc comment.
[ERROR] src\test\java\info\magnolia\demo\travel\setup\TravelDemoModuleVersionHandlerTest.java[75] (javadoc) JavadocType: Missing a
 Javadoc comment.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Magnolia Travel Demo (parent pom) .................. SUCCESS [  4.489 s]
[INFO] Magnolia Travel Demo Module ........................ FAILURE [ 34.003 s]
```

Comment: Also it's strange that it doesn't build normally. can you tell me what's the error and which class?

Comment: @Ducaz035  `mvn clean install` failed with Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (default) on project magnolia-travel-demo: You have 3 Checkstyle violations.
`mvn -e clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip=true`

Comment: which class though?

Comment: I don't know how to format answer. Sorry... Running `mvn -e -X clean install` gives errors in checkstyle plugin:

Comment: @Ducaz035: I've updated post with console output

Comment: That's super bizarre, which version of travel-demo is that? because simply we no longer have javadoc requirements for the tests. I assume if you update to   <parent>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.maven.poms</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-parent-pom-community</artifactId>
    <version>34</version>
  </parent> then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Yes, in 'yesterday' cloned project I have: <parent>
    <groupId>info.magnolia.maven.poms</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-parent-pom-community</artifactId>
    <version>34</version>
  </parent>

Comment: Well, it works for me :( I'm out of ideas there.

Comment: Could it be repository in maven's settings.xml? mine is pointed to : https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/enterprise/ and server id: magnolia.nexus.enterprise; mirror: http://mis-nexus/nexus/content/groups/public

Comment: It shouldn't be related, checkstyle is independent from that but frankly i'm out of ideas now. anyways the initial problem is resolved now, right?

Comment: I was able to build project by skipping tests. Now I can't start app in Tomcat due to exception:  Module Magnolia Admincentral (version 5.6.0) is dependent on imaging (version 3.4/*), which was not found.

 at info.magnolia.module.model.reader.DependencyCheckerImpl.checkDependencies(DependencyCheckerImpl.java:70)
There lot of modules print error about their dependencies

Comment: Try to get one of those packs, https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ce-packs/browse and build your webapp on top of it. Then you will have all necessary dependencies automatically. and only need to adjust travel-demo to snapshot version of yours.

Comment: Trying to clone `Cloning into 'ce-packs'...
Password for 'https://magnolia_training@git.magnolia-cms.com':` ???? Asked for password. It's comunity edition!  LOL

Comment: What really frustrate me is that I can build and run `training-developer-project`, I can build `demo-project` but if try repeat that in my project I hit all possible hidden problems

Comment: I was able to clone from `https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/PLATFORM/repos/ce-packs.pub/browse` . how can I use it?  Thank you, Ducaz035 fo r your help!

Comment: Basically there is community edition pack in it, override the travel-demo version in that pom and deploy that webapp.

Comment: Thanks Ducaz035, I finally build and run travel demo within my project. I can see pages within page application. There only one problem left. Any image in template cause exception during rendering.
  SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
  FreeMarker template error:
  When calling macro "image", required parameter "image" (parameter #1) was specified, but had null/missing value.

Comment: Himm perhaps those images are not published?

Comment: But nevertheless we should close the topic here and continue with other question should you have because we diverted the discussion into different topics already :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in into the webapp, you are talking about the bundle so add the travel-demo to it as maven dependency. Alternative you can drop the jar to /libs folder and Magnolia will it pick up automatically. For more detail please check
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS55/Installing+a+module

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you Ducaz035. My idea was to make `travel demo` project part of my  study project. So I would be able to change and add my pages, components etc.while I learn. Both options you mention 'include as dependencies' or 'add jar` make this not possible... Or I completely misunderstood concept?

Comment: If you include as jar, you have to replace the jar everytime which is not nice. However, If you add it as dependency you can use JVM HotSwap when you have both project open on any IDE. And IDE will handle that automatically. Check this out, https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-auto-reload-a-web-application-hot-deploy/.

Comment: Also magnolia has a solution for that, https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Light+development+in+Magnolia. Idea is that you define a directory in the file system and magnolia observes it for changes. Should detected, it automatically reloads the resources.